# Bounded Sequence in $L^p$ is Tight

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

For $1 < p < \infty$, suppose that $\{f_n\}$ is bounded in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$. Is $\{fn\}$ tight?

**We defined tight as :** A family of measurable functions is said to be tight over $E$ provided for each $\epsilon >0$ there is a subset $E_0 \subseteq E$  of finite measure for which $\int_{E - E_0} |f| < \epsilon$

How do I prove this or a counterexample works? Any help. Thanks

Comment: Take a fixed $f\in L^p $ and consider $f_n = f (\cdot -n) $ on $\Bbb {R} $ with Lebesgue measure as a counterexample.

Comment: sorry, what is $\cdot$ for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Tight convergence" excludes the possibility of mass escaping to $\infty$. Take as an example $f_n = \chi_{[n,n+1]}$. The sequence $\{f_n\}$ is bounded in $L^p$ but isn't tight. If it were, you would have
$$m([n,n+1] \setminus E_0) = \int_{\mathbb R \setminus E_0} |f_n| < \epsilon$$
so that 
$$m([n,n+1] \cap E_0) > 1 - \epsilon$$ for all $n$. In this case $E_0$ couldn't have finite measure.

Comment: do you mind expand on how you got to $m([n,n+1] \cap E_0) > 1 - \epsilon$ , I am confuse at this step? thanks

Comment: If a subset of $[n,n+1]$ has measure less than $\epsilon$, its complement has measure greater than $1 - \epsilon$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Why does $m([n,n+1] \cap E_0) > 1 - \epsilon$ imply $m(E_0)=\infty$? I think if you redefine $f_n = \chi_{[n,n+1)}$ for $n \in \Bbb{Z}$, then one can obtain the desired contradiction, since $m([n,n+1) \cap E_0) > 1 - \epsilon$ for all $n \in \Bbb{Z}$ implies $$m(E_0) = m(\bigcup_{n \in \Bbb{Z}} [[n,n+1) \cap E_0] = \sum m([n,n+1) \cap E_0) \ge \sum (1-\epsilon) = \infty.$$ Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you though.

Comment: @user193319 It's not clear what your objection is.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I guess what I'm trying to say is that I don't think you can conclude $m(E_0)=\infty$ unless you define $f_n$ as I did, since the sets $[n,n+1]$ with $n \in \Bbb{N}$ do not partition $E_0$ in the way that $[n,n+1)$ with $n \in \Bbb{Z}$ do.

Comment: @user193319 You must be aware that $m([n,n+1] \cap E) = m([n,n+1)\cap E)$.